# file_get_contents($url) returning extra data with some servers

Tags: php, iis

I made a simple script to isolate my problem :

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sitlor.fr/photos/754/754000273_4.jpg";
file_put_contents("test.jpg", file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

In this case and with this file in particular, `file_get_contents()` add extra bytes in the beggining of the file.

When `$url` is an url to an other image, it does work normally.

Some `$url` causing trouble :

```
$url = "http://www.sitlor.fr/photos/754/754000273_4.jpg";
$url = "http://www.sitlor.fr/photos/754/754005986_4.jpg";
$url = "http://www.sitlor.fr/photos/754/754002719_4.jpg";
```

If I use a `curl` script, it works well :

```
function curly($url) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $content = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

file_put_contents("test.jpg", curly("http://www.sitlor.fr/photos/754/754000273_4.jpg"));
```

But I can't : I need `getimagesize()` too and it returns `false` when I use it on the problematics files.

I also noticed that the problem occurs only on my remote server. When I try theses scripts locally, it works fine.

---

**Edit:**

I added the `IIS` tag because I can see they are using a IIS Server from the response HTTP header :

```
Server :"Microsoft-IIS/6.0"
X-Powered-By :"ASP.NET"
X-AspNet-Version :"4.0.30319"
```

---

**Edit 2:**

Here is the binary difference (`vbindiff` output) of the files.

It seems that the extra parts is `33 32 34 0D 0A` (I have no idea what it means) :

```
/tmp/original.jpg                                                               
0000 0000: FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46  49 46 00 01 01 01 01 2C  ......JF IF.....,  
0000 0010: 01 2C 00 00 FF E1 03 BA  45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49  .,...... Exif..II  
0000 0020: 2A 00 08 00 00 00 0B 00  0E 01 02 00 3B 00 00 00  *....... ....;...  

/tmp/extra-bytes.jpg                                                            
0000 0000: 33 32 34 0D 0A FF D8 FF  E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00  324..... ...JFIF.  
0000 0010: 01 01 01 01 2C 01 2C 00  00 FF E1 03 BA 45 78 69  ....,.,. .....Exi  
0000 0020: 66 00 00 49 49 2A 00 08  00 00 00 0B 00 0E 01 02  f..II*.. ........
```

Comment: Only the `iss` tag gives clues that your using `iss`, your need to debug this more yourself as we cant reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ I can't debug this myself : `www.sitlor.fr` is a webservice I don't own. The problem is in their side ? I added the `IIS` tag because the use a IIS server

Comment: That's fine, but in my tests all of them images downloaded and worked fine, no issues with getimagesize on them, no issues at all. If the files work locally for you but not on your *distant server* then your need to compare setups. I cant think of a reason it would add *extra bytes* to only these files and not all the files. Also what are the *extra bytes*?

Comment: I added the binary diff between the two files.